# What is the best way to check if a value in a table has changed when writing to a database?

Tags: oracle, database-design, select, insert

Let me provide you with an example. Let's say I have an `html_tag` with two columns, `tag_type` and `tag_value`

For example, let's say I have a record with the value "link" under the`tag_type` field and "https://dba.stackexchange.com" under the `tag_value` field.

Now, how would I approach this for auditing purposes? I want to only `INSERT` into this table when one of the `tag_value` fields corresponding to a `tag_type` has changed, because it would not make sense to add redundant records to this table.

Is this a database design problem I'm having, or is there advanced SQL I'm unaware of that would accomplish this? Or, rather, would the Java I am getting these values from initially be the place to handle such a thing? Example of how I would do this in Java (psuedo code):

```
var newTag = extract the tag's value from my webpage;

var tag_value = SELECT tag_value from html_tag
WHERE tag_type = 'link'

if (new_tag != tag_value) then (INSERT INTO html_tag)...
```

Should I handle this at the database level, or java level, like directly above?

Answer (score 0):

If you need combination of `(tag_value,tag_type)` to be unique , the only guaranteed way to do it is to add unique constraint or unique index, e.g. 
`alter table  html_tag add constraint UQ_HTML_TAG_COMPOSITE UNIQUE(tag_value, tag_type)` .  In addition you can modify INSERT statement so it will not insert a record if it already exists. Something like

```
INSERT INTO html_tag(tag_value,tag_type) 
SELECT 'dba.stackexchange' as tag_value, 'link' as tag_type FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
  SELECT NULL FROM  html_tag a WHERE a.tag_value = 'dba.stackexchange' 
  and a.tag_type = 'link'
)
```

will greatly reduce (not 100% though due to concurrency) chances of inserting duplicate records.  You  may also try using `MERGE`. However, no matter how you insert the record, the only way to completely avoid duplicates is to enforce it on DB level by adding unique constraint /index.